# RMII and diferential pairs

Tags: differential

I am initializing my differential pairs in my schematic.
I have a RMII port and i can't find information on which signals are differential pairs.

Maybe IND*, OUTD*, NON?

Here are my signals :

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those signals are for a MII port (Media independent Interface), not RMII (reduced MII). None of those signals are differential pairs.

On the other side of the PHY you will find the interface to the Ethernet magnetics (the transformers). These signals are usually labelled TXN/TXP and RXN/RXP. These are differential pairs.

For PCB layout guidelines you should follow the datasheet for the PHY that you're using.